# Bit order in MAC frames

Tags: ethernet

I have the impression that when an Ethernet transmitter sends a frame, it sends lowest positioned bytes first, but I've never looked at the datastream on the ports. So how are the groups of bytes select to send? For example, if the destination address is "00:11:22:33:44:55", the source address is "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", when start sending a frame, will it send 0x"554433221100" and then 0x"ffeeddccbbaa", i.e., select fields (dest_addr, src_addr) and then send them separately at low-to-high byte order? Will it also reverse bit order (send "5" as 0x"a")?

Comment: traditionally, as Ethernet was developed using computers with big-endian, the TCP IP Stacks work with this byte order. I guess they do not change that when putting bits n bytes on the bus

Comment: There’s ethernet and there’s tcp. The questions you ask can be simply answered by Wikipedia. For the bit order on ethernet, ‘ethernet frame’ in Wikipedia tells all. Then look for tcp.